# Wordpress - automatically close mobile menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile, menu

Really hoping you can help. I'm using Wordpress to build a basic website to promote my new business. I'm fairly tech savvy, but I'm not a developer and I can only really use CSS and a bit of HTML.

I've got a problem where the mobile menu of my website does not close when selected which is really annoying. My website can be seen [here](http://edtechhub.co.uk/).

I've been into the Editor of Wordpress and found a piece of code which (as a complete guess) might control the click of the mobile menu:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".site-nav-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".site-nav").toggle();
 });  

 $('.main-nav > li ').click(function(){
     $('.main-nav > li ').removeClass('current');
      var css_class = $(this).attr("class");
      $('.'+css_class.replace(/\ +/g,".") ).addClass('current');
     });
```

Could anyone help me find the problem and let me know if they think they have a fix?

Really appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.main-nav > li ').click(function() {
  $('.main-nav > li ').removeClass('current');
  var css_class = $(this).attr("class");
  $('.' + css_class.replace(/\ +/g, ".")).addClass('current');
  $(".site-nav").fadeOut(); //At this point you can fade out the menu
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. So do I just replace the current piece of code directly with yours? Or is it in addition? Apologies, but really out of my depth on this one!

Comment: `$(".site-nav").fadeOut();` is a new line. You can add it to your code. Or you can replace the click function with this one.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try shortly and will let you know!

Comment: No luck unfortunately, thanks for the reply Alex. The menu still appears open regardless of whether I add it as a new line or replace the click function.

Comment: Alex - I suspect your code may have worked but I had a caching problem. Really appreciate your input!

Comment: Hi Alex. Your fix suffers from the same issue as above. Although this fixes the  mobile menu issue, it actually breaks the menu on Safari for Mac and iPads for non-mobile menus. When you select a menu option and the page scrolls to the correct section, scrolling back upto the menu and the menu has gone. You need to refresh the page to get the menu back. Do you know how to fix this? I've left your fix in place for now so you can see the problem in action (if you have a access to safari)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.main-nav > li ').click(function(){
   $('.site-nav').slideUp() 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this piece  of code be in addition to what is already there, or as a replacement?

Comment: Welcome. You have to add this line `$('.site-nav').slideUp() ;` in click function `$('.main-nav > li ').click(function(){     
$('.site-nav').slideUp() ;
     });`

Comment: I've tried replacing the current click function with this code and unfortunately it doesn't  work.

Comment: You don't have to replace the code. You have to add this line `$('.site-nav').slideUp(); ` . I have applied it in console. It's work.

Comment: Hmmmm, strange. This is what the code now looks like: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".site-nav-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".site-nav").toggle();
 });  

 $('.main-nav > li ').click(function(){
 $('.site-nav').slideUp() 
  }); Does this look correct?

Comment: Thank you so much Ankita! Looks like I had a caching problem on the site. It is now working great!

Comment: Most Welcome...:)

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, although this fixes the issue, it actually breaks the menu on Safari for Mac and iPads for non-mobile menus. When you select a menu option and the page scrolls to the correct section, scrolling back upto the menu and the menu has gone. You need to refresh the page to get the menu back. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Why you want to refresh page..? You have to click again on menu button.

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page, but that is the only way to get the menu back. With your fix in place, if you click a non-mobile menu in safari (it works fine on chrome) my homepage scrolls to the appropriate section on the website, but if you scroll back up to the top, the entire menu has disappeared, and the only way to get the menu back is by refreshing the entire website.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by Ankita seems to have worked beautifully. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
 $('.main-nav > li ').click(function(){
    $('.site-nav').slideUp() 
     });
```